# Child Component is not being notify when there are errors

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am using angular `parent/child` communication between two components, I am able to get the changes made by the parent in the `onChanges` life cycle from the child component, but the problem is that when there are errors the changes are not applied to the child component.

**Parent:**

```
confirm() {
      this.someService.saveSomthing(someObject).subscribe(data => {
        if (data === 1) {
          this.showConfirmation = false;   <--- child is being notified 
          this.alertService.showMessage('success');
        }
      }, error => {
          this.showConfirmation = true;   <--- child is not being notified
        this.alertService.showMessage(
          'Validation Error'
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `showConfirmation` was `false` before? ChangeDetection doesn't get triggered if the value is the same

Comment: How does show confirmation work?  If true is is supposed to show something?  Did you try changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()?

Comment: @CristianTraìna omg that was the problem, I did't know that the change detection will not be fired unless there are changes (what ironic).

Comment: There are better systems to notify a child, you can try using an `EventEmitter` and emit `true` or `false` according to your needs. In this way, you can emit `false` several times and it will work without triggering the change detection in all the components tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better systems to notify a child, you can try using an EventEmitter and emit true or false according to your needs. In this way, you can emit false several times and it will work without triggering the change detection in all the components tree:

```
// parent.ts
showConfirmationEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

...
error => {
  this.showConfirmationEvent.emit(false);
} 

// parent.html

<child [showConfirmationEvent]="showConfirmationEvent">

// child.ts

@Input() showConfirmationEvent: EventEmitter<boolean>;

...

ngOnInit() {
   this.showConfirmationEvent.subscribe(value => {
     // use your boolean
   });
}
```